# Want to halt code until user uses a button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

So I am trying to run a code, open a GUI window, choose between two buttons, which set a value and then with this value continue the rest of the code.

I have seen similar questions or Tutorials, but I do not find the suitable solution for my problem.

As I have already seen, **JFrame**, **ActionListener** and **ActionEvent** have to be used in order to make a GUI with a button.

An Object which extends JFrame and implements ActionListener is writen in the main method.

The Problem is, that the code writen in the *main method* opens the GUI window and continues to run. I just want that the code waits till the user clicks a button and then continue.

A sub-solution is, to write the code that I want in the **actionPerformed** method but:

- The GUI window remains open, after the selection of a button
- It makes no sense to me to write the rest of the code in the **actionPerformed** method.

Or to write a while loop until a button is clicked. A more sensible solution has to exist that I am not aware of or I do not understand the way this should work.

Here is a part of the code.

```
@Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == testStringA) {
            setVariableTo = "testString_a";
            try {
                runMethodWithNewVariable(setVariableTo);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            setVariableTo = "project";
            try {
                runMethodWithNewVariable(setVariableTo);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you wanting your `main()` method to block after calling `setVisible()` on your JFrame?

Comment: Yes exactly. I initialize the GUI object in the main method, setVisible(true) and later follows another method which uses the users input. It just makes sense, that the code will just run and will not stop for the users input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the begining of your program, show a modal `JDialog` to the user! You can do this using `JOptionPane.show()` methods, like this:

```
String[] buttonTexts = {"first","second"}; //create the button texts here

//display a modal dialog with your buttons (stops program until user selects a button)
int userDecision =  JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"title","Select a button!",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,null,buttonTexts,buttonTexts[0]);

//check what button the user selected: stored in the userDecision
// if its the first (left to right) its 0, if its the second then the value is 1 and so on

if(userDecision == 0){
  //first button was clicked, do something
} else if(userDecision == 1) {
  //second button was clicked, do something
} else {
 //user canceled the dialog
}

//display your main JFrame now, according to user input!
```

Comment: Jap! This is what I was looking for :) As a side note. The pop-up window in (win10) does not trigger a notification similar to the one with JFrame (orange "flashin" light) in the task bar making it difficult to see when multiple programms are open. Is there an option for that?

Comment: https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-flash-the-window-taskbar-in-swing/ Found this, could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a JFrame, why don't you use a JOptionPane (showOptionDialog) with two buttons, "string A" and "project" instead of "Yes" and "No", for example?

JOptionPanes like "show Option Dialog" are intrinsically blocking.  If you put one in your main() method, execution will "wait" for the user to select something in the dialog and the dialog will return an indicator to what was selected before execution in main() continues.

Answer (score 3):

You basically have two threads running - the main thread and the GUI thread. You don't explicitly create the GUI thread but it is there.

You can use a number of techniques to synchronise these two threads. The most basic is the good old `synchronized`, `wait` and `notify`. Something a `Semaphore` can also be used. In the main thread you would create the GUI and wait until a condition is met. In the GUI thread (i.e. actionPerformed) you would notify.